# Georgia typeface renders poorly on MacOS and iOS

Tags: typefaces, web-safe, cross-platform

I have been looking for a cross-platform friendly typeface, and in this regard Georgia seemed like a safe choice - or so I thought. After using it for a few days on MacOS, it seemed a bit off in some circumstances. Some text frankly didn't look good. On Windows 10 this never was a problem. This led to a direct comparison:

| Switching between Georgia on MacOS and Windows |
| --- |
| [image: Comparison between MacOS and Windows] |

Looking at the heading on MacOS, the letter *a* and *t* overshoots, the serifs of *i* and *t* fuse together. Overall the body text is considerably more (too much) kerned. Maybe its just me, but I find these discrepancies annoying, especially when I know how well this typeface can be displayed. I even copied over the Georgia typeface that comes with Windows to MacOS, just to be sure that MacOS didn't have a "lesser variant", but they are exactly the same. Apple font smoothing is turned off, and the issue retains across all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) and applications. The issue applies to iOS as well.

I would go so far as to say that Georgia isnʻt web-safe. Do we just have to accept this level of difference in font rendering?

Comment: Have you made the same systematic comparison with other fonts? Are you sure Georgia is the only font that change appearance? (And btw isn't the term "web-safe" obsolete now that font embedding is widely supported in browsers?)

Comment: There are fundamental differences in how Windows and MacOS render fonts, but MacOS usually do justice to the design of the typeface. However, I find this not to be the case with Georgia, which is a shame because it is great for both screen and paper when rendered "correctly".

Comment: I realise web-safe might not be the correct term in this case. What I mean is "render nicely" across platforms.

Comment: Once opened in Ps to eliminate the annoying gif flicking back & forth, I prefer the Mac render at 'real' size. The Windows looks 'scratchy' & over-spread. I read all my books on the phone/pad in Georgia, so it's a font I'm very used to.

Comment: Also, are you using the exact same version in both platforms?

Comment: Yes, the issue seems to be related to how each operating system handle font rendering. Given that Georgia is developed for Microsoft, I wonder if its design is optimised for the way Windows renders fonts.

Comment: The Mac version in your gif is a **completely different font.** Every letter is different. In particular, the cross-bar of capital A is higher: that's not a rendering issue.

Comment: It is the exact same font used in both cases - the same typeface file and identical CSS styling. The resulting differences are the same independent of browser being used.